# get json data and images

Tags: c#, json, api, asp.net-web-api

I have Web Api Controller which get list of cars from database

```
[HttpGet, Route("list")]
public object List()
{
    var cars = context.Cars.ToList();        
    return Json(cars);
}
```

Response looks like

```
[{
   "markName": "Chevrolet",
   "modelName": "Spark EV",
   "year": 2014,
   "id": 1
},
{
   "markName": "Chevrolet",
   "modelName": "Volt",
   "year": 2014,
   "id": 2
}]
```

Also I have a function to get image by id

```
[HttpGet, Route("{id}/photo")]
        public IActionResult GetPhoto(int id)
        {
            string path = "blalblabla"
            Byte[] b = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);         
            return File(b, "image/jpeg");
        }
```

How can I get ALL data (json and images) in one request? Or i should do this some other way?

Comment: Both the action methods are of different routes. You might create another function which will fetch the JSON values and the images (as a stream of bytes) and store them in a single custom model-collection. Then, you can call that function which will return you the JSON and the stream of bytes of the image. You will need to read the bytes and convert it to your file format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a view model to encapsulate all the desired information. Include a url to where to get the image along with the other metadata

for example.

```
public class CarModel {
  public string markName { get; set; }
  public string modelName { get; set; }
  public int year { get; set; }
  public int id { get; set; }
  public string photo { get; set; }
}
```

You would then include a link to the photo action

```
[HttpGet("list")]
public IActionResult List() {

    var cars = context.Cars.AsEnumerable();
    var models = cars.Select(car => 
                            new CarModel {
                                markName = car.markName,
                                modelName = car.modelName, 
                                year = car.year,
                                id = car.id,
                                photo = Url.RouteUrl("CarPhoto", new { id = car.id })
                            }).ToList();

    return Ok(models);
}

[HttpGet("{id}/photo", Name = "CarPhoto")]
public IActionResult GetPhoto(int id) {
    string path = "blalblabla"
    Byte[] b = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);         
    return File(b, "image/jpeg");
}
```

An example response could look like

```
[{
   "markName": "Chevrolet",
   "modelName": "Spark EV",
   "year": 2014,
   "id": 1,
   "photo": "cars/1/photo"
},
{
   "markName": "Chevrolet",
   "modelName": "Volt",
   "year": 2014,
   "id": 2
   "photo": "cars/2/photo"
}]
```